# Text wrapped to right of image not aligning to the top of the page

Tags: html, css

On my website, I have some text that wraps to the side of my image. I have the parent container for both of these aligned to the top of the page, but the text does not follow. Can you help the text come in line with the image, like in a navigation bar.

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
}
#icon-top-corner-wrapper {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: lightBlue;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
#icon-top-corner {
    width: 100%;
}
#toolbar {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
    <div id="icon-top-corner-wrapper">
        <img alt="Digytool Icon" id="icon-top-corner" src="https://system.digytool.com/img/icon/digytool.png" title="Digytool">
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <h1>
            Digytool
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: body { margin:0; } h1 {margin:0} better to make a class for that h1 or ID

Comment: Yes that works perfect, I do have an id for that h1 but i removed it for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Mostafa Baezid I solved it by adding

```
body {
    margin: 0;
} 
h1 {
    margin:0
}
```

to my CSS to close the gaps.